# How do I disable a column in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I'm updating an old MySQL database and find that several columns in various tables are not needed.  But rather than just remove the columns, I'd like to disable them temporarily so I can test the code and see how many things break before I decide to complete remove the column.  How can I tell the server to throw an error if a particular column is accessed?

Comment: You may just rename them

Comment: ^^ Exactly. If the code references them by name, it will fail. However, if the code uses `SELECT *` and expects them to be there, you can't guard against that. It will fail later when you've removed the columns. (one reason to avoid `SELECT *`)

Comment: I must admit, I've never considered the pitfalls of SELECT *  .  Thanks for pointing that out.  And the rename idea is good, something like columnname1.  But is there a way to "comment out" a column similar to what I would do with commenting a function in code?

Comment: @myk Not that I'm aware of.  If this were my application, I would copy the database entirely, drop the columns, and point the application at the modified copy to test it.

Comment: As far as I know MySQL doesn't include "built-in" capabilities to hide columns. On a simple set of data you may try "clone" whole DB and delete those columns in tables and then watch what will happen

Answer (score 0):

You may rename table oldname to newname and create view using oldname. that view look like column removed table. if have some problem. you just change name table and view.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a view for this.  As an example I created this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8947/2

Take a look at the two queries.  One selects the table with the column you aren't sure you need (which I called "legacyData").  The other selects the view.  You can see that in the view, the column "legacyData" no longer exists.

I don't think this will work if you are writing from the table, but if you are reading from the table a view is a viable option.

The steps you'd want to take in production to try it out would be:

- Rename your table ('myTable' to 'myTableDontUse', for example)
- Create the view based on the newly renamed table
- When you name the view, name it the table's original name (myTable in this example)

By doing that, you've replaced your table with a view.  This approach would allow you to see if applications are accessing the legacyData field of that table.  If not, you can remove the view, rename your table, and drop the column in question.

Performance typically is not great with a view especially if you have a lot of data, so be careful of that.  In a similar situation, I started out with a view but due to performance reasons (table had 2M+ rows), we changed to a normal table that was instead populated via triggers.